# understanding old vul ms08-067

Tags: c++, windows, security

I am trying to understand how the very old vulnerability MS08-067 works. I found a code example http://www.phreedom.org/blog/2008/decompiling-ms08-067/.

Debugging this code shows me that below function could overruns the stack:

```
wcscpy(previous_slash, &p[2]);
```

Below screenshot shows status of local vars when the overflow happens:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i9eN.jpg)

What confuses me is: `wcspy` copies the content from `&p[2]` to `previous_slash`, `&p[2]` is part of `previous_slash`, so its length is shorter. How could the overflow happen when the content for triggering overflow is shorter than the length of dst buffer?

Comment: Based on the comments, my guess would be that the issue is a [buffer underflow](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/124.html), i.e., the code is overwriting memory before the beginning of the buffer, not after the end.

Comment: One possible complicating factor, though: unless I'm missing something, the code as posted attempts to write into a constant string, so you may be seeing an exception that isn't actually related to the vulnerability.  Probably best to rewrite main() to use an actual buffer rather than a constant string.